# How to design class using page object model for 2 tabs with same functionality

Tags: selenium, pageobjects

while running the application, 2 new tabs open which has same functionalities.Using Page object model  in selenium how to design a class for this. If single class is enough how to differentiate those 2 tabs

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium WebDriver has a `WindowHandles` property and a `SwitchTo()` method, which you can use to switch across the tabs. After switching, you can use the same class, probably even the same instance, to address your page objects.